# CouchDB null value when sort descending

Tags: view, mapreduce, couchdb

I have CouchDB view that gives me a correct value in natural order and a null when sorted descending, here are the Futon screenshots:

[Natural order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhViX.png)

[Descending order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGNSU.png)

Here is the view code:

```
"informe_precios": {
           "map": "function(doc){if(doc.doc_type=='precio'){emit([doc.comprador,doc.fecha.substr(0,4),doc.fecha.substr(5,2)],{precio:doc.precio,litros:doc.litros});}}",
           "reduce": "function(keys, values, rereduce){var importe= 0; var totallitros = 0;for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {importe += values[i].precio*values[i].litros;totallitros += values[i].litros;}return importe/totallitros;}"
       }
```

I need it descending because I want to get 12 last values.

TIA
Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always assuming that your `reduce` function is called with the output of your `map` function, ie. you're not handling the `rereduce` situation.

In the `rereduce` your `values` will be the `importe/totallitros` values from previous `reduce` calls.

Your reduce function is getting a "price per liter" average for each month, so because it's an average there's no way for your `rereduce` function to actually handle that data because for the multiple `values` coming in there's no way to know their weight in the average.

So, you'll need to change your function to return the count so that you can use that to weight the average in the `rereduce` function (we're also using the inbuilt `sum` function to make things simpler):

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  if (rereduce) {
    var length = sum(values.map(function(v){return v[1]}));
    var avg = sum(values.map(function(v){
      return v[0] * (v[1] / length)
    }));
    return [avg, length];
  }
  else {
    var importe= 0;
    var totallitros = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      importe += values[i].precio * values[i].litros;
      totallitros += values[i].litros;
    }
    return [ importe/totallitros, values.length ];
  }
}
```

The final result you'll see in your view here will be an array, so you'll always need to pick out the first element of that in your client code.